# Call a static method inside other static method of a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a class with some static methods.
I am trying to call one of my static methods inside another static method of the same class.

I have tried to call it with `this.constructor.method();` and it doesn't work because the right this is not binded properly there.

I have also tried to bind the right this to the method were i want to call the other method. `this.constructor.listenerFunc.bind(this.constructor)`. Still not working.

Here is how the code looks like:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
    };

    static firstMethod(){
        //do some things
        this.constructor.secondMethod();
    };

    static secondMethod(){
        //do other things
    };
}

var x = new MyClass;

console.log(x)
```

Comment: can't you use `MyClass.secondMethod()` instead of `this.constructor.secondMethod();`  (note u have a typo in `secondMethod` function name)

Comment: You have a typo in the method name.

Comment: this code is just an example. corrected the typo(that wasn't my problem)

Comment: ```MyClass.secondMethod()``` works fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the typo, which prevents your example from working, [you can use both the `this.` notation and a classical static call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
    };

    static firstMethod(){
        this.secondMethod();
        MyClass.secondMethod();
    };

    static secondMethod(){
        console.log('I was called!');
    };
}

MyClass.firstMethod();
```

Comment: Only ```MyClass.secondMethod();``` works just fine. Thanks for your help.